# Angular 5 issue with mockbackend/XHRBackend test

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to write test using MockBackEnd service so I inject MockBackEnd and my own service which I want to mock, after that I try to listen subscribe on mocakBackEnd instance and calllike below but unable to access the subscribe mean its not getting inside the subscribe block.

```
mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
    (connection: MockConnection) => {
      console.log(connection);
      expect(connection.request.method).toBe(RequestMethod.Get);
      expect(connection.request.url).toBe(expectedUrl);

      connection.mockRespond(new Response(
        new ResponseOptions({ body: mockResponse })
      ));
    });
```

So I also tried XHRBackend service but not able to access connection on instance of XHRBackend so please help how can I get rid of this.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use HttpClient instead of the old, deprecated Http service. It has a much better support for testing, among other benefits. And it's out since Angular 4.3.

Comment: @JBNizet We alredy using HttpClient but no luck to access  mockbacked.connections.subscribe

Comment: MockBackend is part of the old, deprecated Http module that you now say that you're not using, since you're using HttpClient. Look at your imports. If you import something from `@angular/http`, you're doing it wrong. Everything about the HttpClient is under `@angular/common/http`. Read the documentation. It explains how to test code using HttpClient: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks